# Структура переменных и объединений в С

Tags: c

Уважаемые программисты :)

Не могли вы бы мне объяснить, что такое структура в С? Для чего она? и привести небольшой пример?

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Структура в языке C, это "пользовательский" тип с набором некоторых полей. Позволяет хранить, по просту говоря скопом, набор логически объединенных данных, что необходимо в ходе решения многих задач. Пример, запись о студенте в журнале:

```
struct student{
    char stud_first_name[18];
    char stud_second_name[18];
    int stud_avg_max;
};
```

Затем вы можете создавать переменные типа "student", и работать с его полями. Лучше конечно, об этом почитать: "Б. Керриган, Д. Ритчи - Язык программирования C"